# Error in enum returning function in interface with generic type

Tags: c#, generics, interface, enums

I think the code says more than a complete description:

```
public interface IBank
{
    Bank.EType Type { get; }
}


public abstract Bank<T>: ...
{
    public enum EType { Int, Gm, User };

    private EType _type;

    public EType Type { get { return _type; } }
}
```

I get the error:

> *Using the generic type PcgTools.Mmodel.Common.Synth.Bank requires type arguments*

How should I define the prototype in the interface to get no errors?

Comment: On what line is this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error suggests, the `Bank` class requires type arguments which you have not supplied. You could choose a type for `T` e.g.

```
Bank<string>.EType Type { get; }
```

but this probably isn't what you want since this would defeat the purpose of making `Bank` generic in the first place.

The types `Bank<int>.EType` and `Bank<string>.EType` are different types and cannot be compared, so you should move it into a non-generic class or to the top level:

```
public abstract class Bank
{
    public enum EType { Int, Gm, User };
}

public abstract class Bank<T> : Bank
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer ...actually I could not use a base class (since I already used it because of lightmvvm's ObservableObject), but I just made another 'normal' class with the type in it which works fine.